# Move semantic for method redundant move call

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Say that I have this class

```
struct Test {
  std::string a;
  void setA(std::string&& input) {
    a = input;
    input = "";
  }
}
```

Here I move the content of `input` into `a` and then I leave `input` on a safe destructable state. This is the classic use of the move semantic where I can avoid copies.

Now say that I have this class

```
struct Test {
  std::string a;
  void setA(std::string&& input) {
    DoSomeWork(input);
  }
  void DoSomeWork(std::string&& other) { /* ... */}
}
```

Is this still correct? or should I use `DoSomeWork(std::move(input));`? I do not know if the move is required or not in this case.

---

**Note.**
In case 1 I receive an rvalue reference as input and I use the classic approach.

```
void setA(std::string&& input) {
  a = input;   //input is an rvalue referece and I "transfer" its content into a
  input = "";  //maybe useless but in some books (including c++ primer) I've seen that it's good practice to "reset" the moved-from object and leave it in a destructable state!
```

I understand that. What I cannot understand is:

```
void setA(std::string&& input) {
  //recall that DoSomeWork accepts a std::string&&
  DoSomeWork(input);
}
```

Here if I want to pass `input` to the function and move it I do not know if `std::move` is required. I already have an rvalue reference so is the move process automatic? or the `std::move` call is required?

Comment: Which c++ primer book says to manually put the moved from object in a valid state?  The move constructor should do that for you automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here I move the content of `input` into `a`

No. You're copying the content of `input` to `a`.

You might confuse types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). As a named parameter, `input` is an lvalue; given `a = input;`, the copy assignment operator, but not move assignment operator will be invoked.

> and then I leave `input` on a safe destructable state.

It's superfluous, the work should be left to the move assignment operator of `std::string`.

Yes you should use [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) to convert `input` to rvalue, e.g.

```
void setA(std::string&& input) {
  a = std::move(input); // input is move assigned to a, and left with undetermined but valid state
}
```

and

```
void setA(std::string&& input) {
  DoSomeWork(std::move(input));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I had misunderstood the concept! I thought that having declared input as && was enough to enable move. But from what you've written I have to call std::move everytime that I want to do an move

Comment: @RosannaTrevisan Remember that `std::move` is used to convert lvalue to rvalue.

Comment: @RosannaTrevisan No, `input` is always an lvalue; see the link I posted in my answer about what's lvalue expressions. "the name of a variable..."

Comment: Yeah I've got the point right now so I deleted my question ;)

Answer (score 3):

In the function signature

```
void setA(std::string&& input) { /* ... */ }
```

the variable `input` is bound to an rvalue, but is an lvalue itself. When you want to move-construct another object from it, you need to cast it to an rvalue beforehand:

```
void setA(std::string&& input) {
    a = std::move(input);
}
```

Note that it's unnecessary now to set `input` to an empty string now. You simply shouldn't touch this variable anymore. The same reasoning is true when you pass `input` to some other function:

```
void setA(std::string&& input) {
   /* Cast to rvalue necessary to preserve "rvalue-ness" of the argument: */
   DoSomeWork(std::move(input));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd have another question: is the move constructor the only place where I don't call std::move then? like here: http://prntscr.com/k8xpc9

Comment: You see, in that code snippet I've called `this->a = other.a;` and NOT `this->a = std::move(other.a;)`. I am in the move constructor here. Is that correct?

Comment: You still have to use `std::move` to use move assignment in this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

> Here I move the content of input into a and then I leave input on a safe destructable state. This is the classic use of the move semantic where I can avoid copies.

No, you are not; that is a *copy*. Unless you explicitly use `std::move` on a named `&&`, it's *always* a copy.

Also, when you correctly perform a move, it is not your responsibility to put the previous object in a "safe destructable state"; that's the responsibility of the move constructor/assignment operator.

> Is this still correct?

If by "correct" you mean "perform a move", no. Again, if you want to move from a named variable, you *must* use `std::move` on it. This includes passing it to rvalue reference parameters.

The only exception being a `return <named_variable>;` statement, and even then, "named_variable" has to name a value, not a reference (though C++20 may allow rvalue reference variables to be implicitly moved from in this way).

Comment: I misunderstood the usage of && then! I thought that having  `std::string&& input` ad then the assignment `a = input` was enough to move. But now I understand the EFFECTIVE move is performed only by `std::move`